# How to dynamically add consecutive components to JPanel with no extra vertical space

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Hey I am new to this so pardon any thing amiss.

I am trying to add components to JPanel using GridBagLayout,I have set both `weightx` and `weighty` to 1 and set `anchor` to **NORTH**, the first component obediently anchors to the top of the Panel but the next component anchors with a gap proportional to the remaining height of the panel so it looks like the panel is divided into portions equal to the number of components.

This what happens when i add the first component:

[image]

This is what happens when i add the second component:

[image]

and so on and so forth:

[image]

**color pink is the Jpanel and color cyan is the component**

the component is another Jpanel that holds 4 Jtextfeilds to make up a row.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Table extends JPanel{
/*
Main table class that holds TableRow class as rows

couples with the controller class to update the rows
 */
private final GridBagLayout LAYOUT = new GridBagLayout();
private GridBagConstraints constraints;
private ActionPerformed actionListener;



public Table(){

    setLayout(LAYOUT);
    constraintParams();


}

private void constraintParams() {
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.weightx = 1;
    constraints.weighty = 1;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
}

public void updateRow(String data){
    /*
    accepts Array of String data and passes it to corresponding row to update fields
     */

    System.out.println(getComponentCount());
    boolean updated = false;
    try {
        Component[] components = getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            TableRow previousRow = (TableRow) component;
            if (previousRow.getProductName().equals(data.split("!!!")[0])) {
  //                    previousRow.incrementQuantiy();
  //                    updated = true;
  //                    break;
            }
        }
        if (!updated) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        constraints.gridy = getComponentCount();
        add(new TableRow(),constraints);
        TableRow row = (TableRow) getComponent(getComponentCount() - 1);
        row.updateRow(data);

    }
    Component[] components = getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) component;
        row.setListener(actionListener);
    }

}
```

this is the code that deals with adding the components

Comment: Just [use a JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)?

Comment: thanks, ill be using a Jtable, but i went this way for added challenge, however i am still not clear as to why they are rendered the way they are

Answer (score 1):

```
constraints.weighty = 1;
```

The "weighty" constraint tells each component to grow to fill the extra space.

Since each component has the same "weighty" value each component will get the same extra space.

I would suggest you get rid of that constraint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on constraints.